# is it certain in which register arguments and variables are stored?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, att

I'm still uncertain how registers are being used by the assembler

say I have a program:

```
int main(int rdi, int rsi, int rdx) {

    rdx = rdi;

    return 0;
}
```

Would this in assembly be translated into:

```
movq %rdx, %rdi 

ret rax;
```

I'm new to AT&T and have hard time predicting when a certain register will be used.
Looking at this chart from *Computer Systems - A programmer's perspective*, third edition, R.E. Bryant and D. R. O'Hallaron:

[charter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na2vb.png)

Comment: You forgot the instruction and at&t uses src, dst order so it's `mov %rdi, %rdx`. Of course any optimizing compiler would remove that because `rdx` is not used. Also `ret rax` makes no sense, especially since your code has a `return 0`. That would be e.g. `xor %eax, %eax; ret` to zero `rax` and return.

Comment: try it yourself on https://godbolt.org/ where you can look at GCC, clang, ICC, or MSVC asm output.  (Also for several non-x86 ISAs)

Comment: Using the function name `main()` with three integer arguments is not an obvious choice of name — it is implementation defined what the arguments mean, and most probably actually undefined behaviour.  GCC is likely to complain about an inappropriate signature on the `main()` function.  Ignoring the issue of function name, the code does nothing with the arguments that affects the state of the computation, and the optimizer might well remove the assignment.  There's also nothing that ties the variables with names `rdi`, `rsi`, and `rdx` to any of the registers with similar names.

Comment: Except the sysv abi calling convention of course, which specifies those registers for those arguments.

Comment: cleared quite a bit for me, thanks Jonathan

Answer (score 4):

> Is it certain in which register arguments and variables are stored?

Only at entry and exit of a function.

There is no guarantee as to what registers will be used within a function, even for variables which are parameters to the function. Compilers can (and often will) move variables around between registers to optimize register/stack usage, especially on register-starved architectures like x86.

In this case, a simple assignment operation like `rdx = rdi` may not compile to any assembly code at all, because the compiler will simply recognize that both values can now be found in the register `%rdi`. Even for a more complex operation like `rdx = rdi + 1`, the compiler has the freedom to store the value in any register, not specifically in `%rdx`. (It may even store the value back to `%rdi`, e.g. `inc %rdi`, if it recognizes that the original value is never used afterwards.)

Answer (score 1):

No, it would be translated into:

```
mov %rdi, %rdx # move %rdi into %rdx
xor %eax, %eax # zero return value
ret # return
```

Of course, it's more than likely that `rdx = rdi` (and therefore `mov %rdi, %rdx`) will be removed by the compiler, because `rdx` is not used again.

Credit to [@Jester](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982674/is-it-certain-in-which-register-arguments-and-variables-are-stored/57982754?noredirect=1#comment102374489_57982674) for finding this out before me.

Comment: If you copied this from [Jester's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982674/is-it-certain-in-which-register-arguments-and-variables-are-stored/57982754#comment102374489_57982674) it is common courtesy to give them credit for it. Had you made the post a community wiki post would have helped too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not entirely, but I've added a link to it.